# Neo4j Cypher optimization of complex paginated query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have a rather long and complex paginated query.  I'm trying to optimize it. In the worst case - first, I have to execute the data query in a one call to Neo4j, and then I have to execute pretty much the same query for the count. Of course, I do everything in one transaction. Anyway, I don't like the overall execution time, so I extracted the most common part for both - data and count queries and execute it on the first call. This common query returns the IDs of nodes, which I then pass as parameters to the rest of data and count queries. Now, everything works much faster. One thing I don't like is that a common query can sometimes return quite a large set of IDs.. it can be `20k..50k` `Long` IDs.

So my question is - because I'm doing this in a one transaction - is there a way to preserve such `Set` of IDs somewhere in Neo4j between common query and data/count query calls and just refer them somehow in the subsequent data/count queries without moving between app JVM and Neo4j?

Also, am I crazy for doing this, or is this a good approach to optimize a complex paginated query?

Answer (score 1):

Only with a custom procedure.
Otherwise you'd need to return them.

But usually it's uncommon to both provide counts (even google doesn't provide "real" counts) and data.

One way is to just stream the results with the reactive driver as long as the user scrolls.

Otherwise I would just query for pageSize+1 and return "more than pageSize results".

If you just stream the id's back (and don't collect them as an aggregation) you can start using the id's received already to issue your new queries (even in parallel).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How about using `collect` for `size` as `count` and then `UNWIND` and continue? Is this a bad way?